# Toast isn't showing after an onClickListener action (Android Studio 3)

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to make a toast showing when I click on a button linked by onClickListener.
It is a very simple code with one button
When I click, nothing happens. the Button view is added to the activity_main.xml.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class E002Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_e002);

        final Button welcome = findViewById(R.id.botona);
        welcome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"lifekjh",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I checked almost alll answers here but they are different.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

call the show method on toast as follows

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"lifekjh",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: you are welcome, then you can make it as a correct answer